# How to handle internet connection interruption on iOS using CFNetwork?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ftp

I have implemented an FTP client on the iPhone, but when the connection is interrupted for a moment while download from the FTP server is in progress, the application informs me there is no connection and stops the client.

Here comes the problem: next time i try to start the download process again, the event `stream:handleEvent:` is not fired and the `streamStatus` of the `networkStream` stays on `NSStreamStatusOpening`.

If I manually stop the download process (using the same method which I fire when connection is interrupted), I can then re-download again. I have to relaunch the whole application for the downloading to work again.

Here are the key parts of the code:

```
- (void)downloadFile:(NSDictionary *)file {
    NSURL *url;
    CFReadStreamRef ftpStream;
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"PATH TO FTP FILE" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [self.fileStream open];
    ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url);
    self.networkStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *) ftpStream;
    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];
    CFRelease(ftpStream);
}
```

and the method that is fired when something happens with the stream

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    switch (eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
        [self updateStatus:@"Opened connection"];
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
        NSInteger       bytesRead;
        uint8_t         buffer[32768];
        bytesRead = [self.networkStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
        if (bytesRead == -1) {
            [self stopReceivingWithStatus:@"Network read error"];
        } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
            [self stopReceivingWithStatus:nil];
        } else {
            [self processStreamDataWithBuffer:buffer andReadBytes:bytesRead];
        }
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
        assert(NO);
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
        [self stopReceivingWithStatus:@"Stream open error"];
    } break;
    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
    } break;
    default: {
        assert(NO);
    } break;
}
```

The problem as I said is that after connection interrupted, the events are not fired anymore.

Note: I am using iOS 5 with ARC.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should set the flag to force the stream to close the underlying native socket which by default is not done;

```
[self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket];
```